# calling function with dynamic param

Tags: react-native, function

I need to call a function and pass param ID to it:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.addInstaPost(myInstaPost[i].postId)}
    >
        <Text style={styles.reply}>
            <Icon family="Entypo" size={19} name="reply-all" /> Reply
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

this return error "Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'myInstaPost[i].postId'

if I remove parameter and just display it after text 'replay' for debugging....

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.addInstaPost()}
>
    <Text style={styles.reply}>
        <Icon family="Entypo" size={19} name="reply-all" /> Reply {myInstaPost[i].postId}
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

It is displaying totally fine....

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This has something to do with loop and onPress()...

If I declare variable IE:
var currId = myInstaPost[i].postId;

when I do this:

```
onPress={() => this.addInstaPost(currId)}
```

and then inside addInstaPost I alert parameter I am getting always parameter from first element in the loop....

but when I display it somewhere inside the text... for debugging I am getting proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the `.map` method for this case

```
{myInstaPost.map((item, index) => (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addInstaPost(item?.postId)} key={index}>
  <Text style={styles.reply}>
    <Icon family="Entypo" size={19} name="reply-all" /> Reply
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks, myInstaPost is an array of objects, so If is use 'myInstaPost[i].map' I am getting error 'undefined is not is not a function(near myInstaPost[i].map)' If I declare variable inside loop IE: var currMyInstaPost = myInstaPost[i]; I am getting the same error... If I remove counter myInstaPost.map, then there is no error, but it is displaying all links, not only current.

Comment: Declaring dummy array did the trick it seams... var currMyInstaPost = [];
     currMyInstaPost.push(myInstaPost[i]); and then I did as suggested... {currMyInstaPost.map((item, index) => (.... and it worked well...